Nextjs hydration error. I tried useEffect and suspense ut still error
I'm trying to create web app like spreadsheet.
instead of using table, I use my own components
I want to realize that when you click a cell, the cell turn gray.
I use Nextjs14, app router, typescript.
here is the error message

Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.
See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error

//page.tsx
export default function Home() {
  //in the future, I will use server action and get data as 'lists'
  //but now I just use this 'lists'
  const lists = [
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
  ];
  return (
    <main className="p-3 w-full h-full ">
      <div className=" h-full">
        {/* table */}
        <Table params={{ lists: lists }} />
      </div>
    </main>
  );
}

//Table.tsx

"use client";
import React, { Suspense } from "react";
import RowHeader from "./RowHeader";
import RowData from "./RowData";
import { useClickStates } from "../hooks";

export default function Table({ params }: { params: { lists: number[][] } }) {
  
  const undefinedList: number[] = [];
  params.lists.map((i) => {
    undefinedList.push(0);
  });

  const [clickStates, onClickHandler] = useClickStates({
    params: { size: [params.lists.length, params.lists[0].length] },
  });

  return (
    <div className="overflow-scroll w-full h-full text-basecolor-table ">
      <RowHeader params={{ lists: params.lists.shift() ?? undefinedList }} />

      <div className="w-full mt-2">
        {params.lists.map((rowList, i) => {
          return (
            <RowData params={{ rowIndex: i,
                lists: rowList,
                useClickStates: [clickStates, onClickHandler],}}/>
          ); })}
      </div>

    </div>
  );
}


//RowData.tsx
"use client";

import React, { useState } from "react";
import Cell from "./Cell";
import { useClickStates } from "../hooks";

export default function RowData({params,}: { params: { rowIndex: number; lists: number[]; useClickStates: [boolean[][] | null, (row: number, col: number) => void];}; }) {

  const width = "w-32";
  const [clickStates, onClickHandler] = params.useClickStates;

  return (
    <div className={`h-fit w-fit  text-sm  border-dark-gray-custom  ${
        params.rowIndex === 0 ? "border" : "border-x border-b"} flex `} >

      {params.lists.map((l, i) => {
        return i !== 0 ? (

          /*No vertical dividing line in the first cell on the left, 
          Vertical dividing line only on the left thereafter.*/
          <div key={`r${params.rowIndex}c${i}`}
            className={`${width} h-fit flex items-center  border-dark-gray-custom  border-l ${
              clickStates !== null
                ? clickStates[(params.rowIndex, i)]
                  ? "bg-slate-300"
                  : ""
                : "" }`}
            onClick={() => onClickHandler(params.rowIndex, i)}>
            <div className={`h-fit w-full px-1  `}>
              <Cell params={{ value: l }} />
            </div>
          </div>

        ) : (

          <div  key={`r${params.rowIndex}c${i}`}
            className={`${width} h-fit  flex items-center   ${
              clickStates !== null
                ? clickStates[(params.rowIndex, i)]
                  ? "bg-slate-300"
                  : ""
                : ""  }`}
            onClick={() => onClickHandler(params.rowIndex, i)} >
            <div className={`h-fit  w-full px-1  `}>
              <Cell params={{ value: l }} />
            </div>
          </div>

        );})}
    </div>
  );
}

}

//hooks.ts

"use client";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export const useClickStates = ({ params,}: { params: { size: number[] }; }
): [boolean[][] | null, (row: number, col: number) => void] => {
  
  const clickStates_ini: boolean[][] = [];
  //params.size[0] = 6;
  //params.size[1] = 20;
  for (let row = 0; row < params.size[0]; row++) {
    const rowStates: boolean[] = [];
    for (let col = 0; col < params.size[1]; col++) {
      rowStates.push(false);
    }
    clickStates_ini.push(rowStates);
  }

  const [clickStates, setClickStates] = useState<boolean[][] | null>(null);


  function onClickHandler(row: number, col: number) {
    const newClickStates = [...clickStates_ini];
    newClickStates[row][col] = true;
    setClickStates(newClickStates);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    setClickStates(clickStates_ini);
  }, []);

  return [clickStates, onClickHandler];
};


//Cell.tsx
export default function Cell({ params }: { params: { value: number } }) {
  const height = "h-7";
  return <div className="w-full h-12 flex items-center">{params.value}</div>;
}

RowHeader.tsx is just shown correctly
in hooks.ts
I rewrite
const [clickStates, setClickStates] = useState<boolean[][]>(clickState_ini);
to
const [clickStates, setClickStates] = useState<boolean[][] | null>(null);
and use useEffect
I thought lists was probrem, so I put params.size[0] = 6;  params.size[1] = 20;  for clickState_ini
also I did <Suspense fallback={<Loading/>}> <Table> </Suspense>
but still error
